# Non-linear constraint in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I am using the solver fmincon in matlab and I would like to add a non-linear constraint such that the variable to be optimized has a fixed number of non-zero elements. This number is equal to 25 and fixed as seen in the function below.

I have therefore set my non-linear constraint as follow:

```
nonlcon = @limitSizeBasket;

function [c,ceq] = limitSizeBasket(x,maskTop,maskBottom)
%This function limit the size of the basket

    c = sum(any(x(1,:),1)) - 25;
    ceq = [];
end

x = fmincon(@(x)fun(x,scoreTop,scoreBottom),x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,@(x)nonlcon(x,maskTop,maskBottom),options)';
```

Unfortunately, the resulting values of x seems not to take this constraint into account at all as all x are non-zero. Here I have x is a vector of 70 elements and I would restrict the numbers of non-zero elements to 25 at most. Is there a problem with the way I defined my constraints or is the problem coming from something else?

Comment: Typically we would use a MINLP (Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming) solver to handle such cardinality conditions.

Comment: I know matlab has a MILP solver but I have not heard about MINLP. Do you know any of it?

Comment: MINLP solvers are readily available. E.g. BonMin, Knitro, Couenne, Baron,etc If the nonlinearities are quadratic there is even a wider choice.

Comment: How would you tackle the problem if I need to let the x variables flexible between 2 bounds but I also need to limit the number of non-zero items. Is it best to use MINLP and add variables representing the amount or use FMINCON with an additional constraint as I did? Thank you already for your insights.

Comment: Typically once would use a binary variable to indicate if a variable is nonzero or not. There are standard formulations for this.

Comment: alright so FMINCON with additional binary variable. Thank you. Do you have by any chance somewhere to point where I could read about such way for formulate the problem?

Comment: MINLP modeling is largely the same as for MIP models in this respect. Tons of literature available on this.